# OnClickListener to Spinner ? ??

Tags: android, spinner, onclicklistener

I need an OnClickListener to my Spinner.

I tryed everything i found on the internet, but none of them worked.
Please give me a solution for this:

Got my spinner here:

```
     spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

     ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
     (this, R.array.gyerekek_array, R.layout.my_spinner);

     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);



     spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
     spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ItemChooser());
```

And this is my_spinner.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
    android:text="Sample Text" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="31sp"
    >

</TextView>
```

I tryed everything from stackoverflow and everything else from the internet. I just cant make it...
I cannot add onClickListener to the spinner's default TextView because i dont use the default spinner, i got my own my_spinner.xml.
In Fact, if i add an "ID" to my Text View inside the my_spinner.xml i got a null pointer exception.

I even tryed to add an invisible TextView atop of the Spinner, but then only one view can be sensored by OnClick.

Please help me guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't add an onclicklistener on any adapter view try to use setOntouchlistener hope it will help you

```
spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

     ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
     (this, R.array.gyerekek_array, R.layout.my_spinner);

     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

     spinner.setOnTouchlistener(this); 

     spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
     spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new ItemChooser());
```

//////////////////////////// your listener

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Log.d("Spinner","clicked");
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

use this

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
            int item = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();

        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { }
    });
```

Comment: I need a direct event that will runs my code if i click on the spinner's button. Not the spinner's items.

Comment: Adam Varhegyi use setOntouchlistener for spinner it will help you out surely